# Installed module accessible from python3 but not from 2.7?

Tags: python, module, installation, version

Installed module with pip works in ver3, but not with ver2. Is there a way to make it work with ver2 too. The author says it should work. I just dont know how to force it to install in ver2 dirs :

```
# pip install apted
Collecting apted
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/71/c2bcf92376d3ae65d57111d33f577aca68d343e1b7b1914a3767bfbac18e/apted-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (40kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 40kB 514kB/s 
Installing collected packages: apted
Successfully installed apted-1.0.3
```

Example :

```
$ python -m apted -t {a{b}{c}} {a{b{d}}} -mv
/usr/bin/python: No module named apted

$ python3 -m apted -t {a{b}{c}} {a{b{d}}} -mv
distance:             2
runtime:              0.0001785755157470703
{a{b}{c}} -> {a{b{d}}}
{c} -> None
{b} -> {b{d}}
None -> {d}
```

---

this worked out :

```
 # pip2 install apted
```

Comment: You have to install the module separately for each Python version. Different versions of Python store their modules in different places, so you can't really get around that without messing with your Python installations.

Comment: how do i do that .. i expected pip to install for 2.7 and pip3 for 3 !

Comment: What operating system are you using and how did you install Python? (Regardless of your answer, I strongly recommend just using Python 3, because Python 2 will reach end-of-life in [just two days](https://pythonclock.org/).)

Comment: Make a habit of doing `python3 -m pip install ..` or `python2 -m pip install` for binding it with the specific python. Use the `pip` module from the `python` you need, instead of using the global `pip` which may or may not point to the python you assume you want

Comment: you might want to reconsider how you install python and its works on your machine. If you want to run various environments I can recommend installing python via anaconda. There you can easily create and activate different environments.

Answer (score 0):

this worked out :

```
# pip2 install apted
```